# How to use $in aggregation in Python Eve and assign variable through URL?

Tags: mongodb, eve

How to use '$in' in Aggregation using Python Eve ?

 Previously, i set up my aggregation like this below :

```
'$match': {
    'id_data': {'$in' : ['$id_data']}
 }
```

but when i tested on url like this below

```
url/data?aggregate={"$id_data" : ["5da032b0e819ec90621cd807", "5da02bede819ec90621cd6ad"]}
```

I got error `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: The $first accumulator is a unary operator`.

How is the correct way to setup aggregation using '$in' and  assign variable through the URL ?